# Image show URL does not work in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to Laravel 5, so I have no huge experience in Laravel. I am learning. I have been faced a very critical problem: I upload the image and save the database and my public directory image folder.

And finally I show this image my home page like `localhost/image_upload/public/` but when I show this `localhost/image_upload/public/image/show` URL the image not load but everything is working fine.

Route:

```
//it is work
Route::get('/','SliderController@show');

//it's work
Route::get('/image/show','SliderController@show');
```

controller:

```
public function show(){

    $images = SliderModel::all();

    return view('index',compact('images'));
```

Comment: What is the output of `$images` when you `print_r($images);`?

Comment: how do you store your image? and how do you *show* your image in your view?

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1 :**

You shall show your images by

```
{{ HTML::image("public/yourimage.png", "Logo") }}
```

**Method 2 :**

As you are passing the Slider images from controller,

```
$images = SliderModel::all();
#Here you are getting all the images from SliderModel,
```

You shall do this in your view

Step 1 : 
Do a foreach

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
{{ HTML::image($user->images, "Logo") }}
@endforeach
```

**Note :**

I consider that `images` is the field that you used to store the images path in side `SliderModel` Model (Table refers it)